# Adding Tab character while exporting Excel files to txt

Tags: vba, excel, read-write

I wrote a VBA code which takes certain rows from am Excel sheet, and writes them into a TXT file. 
the code works great, but I have 2 problems -

1. I've added the "vbTab" character between each 2 cells that I copy, and in the TXT file it looks great - but when I try opening it again in Excel, each row appears in one single cell (text only in Column A), without any spaces, and it doesn't get into the columns like it should be...
2. In the TXT file, there's quotations (") at the start and end of each row - and it's not good for my use in the TXT files.

Here's the code:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If (j = 1) And (Cells(i, 1).Value = "~") Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If Not IsInArray(j, IgnoreCol) Then
            If j = LastCol Then
                DataLine = DataLine + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)
            Else
                DataLine = DataLine + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) + vbTab
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If (DataLine <> "") Then
        Write #FileNum, DataLine
        DataLine = ""
    End If
Next i
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that when you read it back in, it all goes into the first cell ("A1")?
How are you reading it back in? Could you show the code for that?

Comment: either use text to columns to transform the text in column 1 into columns delimited by the TAB character, either rename the file as .CSV

Comment: @LimaNightHawk - It all goes in the first cell when I drag the TXT file into the Excel sheet, or when I use "Get Data From Text" option menually through the Excel...

Comment: @AlinI - even when I save it as CSV it all goes in the first cell... and without any spaces/Tabs between the words as it should be...

Comment: I don't really understand. Are there or aren't there Double Quotes in your TXT file?

Comment: Ah, I think the problem might be that your wrapping the entire row inside of double quotes. Try removing the double quotes from the entire row.
Also, if you replaced the `vbTab` with a comma `","` the CSV option would work. If your data has commas in it, you'll also need to wrap each cell between two double quotes (but do not wrap the entire row).

Comment: @AlinI - I have 2 problems, one with the quotations at the start and end of each row, and one that when I'm opening the TXT file again through the Excel the entire row opens at the first cell (only column A has text in it) without any spaces - in-spite of the "vbTab" in the code, and that I can see the tabs in the TXT - I think I didn't right it quite well before, I edited it now...

Comment: @LimaNightHawk the double quotes is another problem - in that file I have about 1000 rows - If there's a different way of writing the TXT file so it won't add the quotations on it's own at the start and end of each row I'd love hearing about it (As I said - that's the second problem, but the way you put it - solving this one also solves the first one...)

Comment: replace **Write** command with **Print** command: **Print #FileNum, DataLine**

Comment: All the code needed was to replace "write" into "Print" - it works now, thank you for your time and effort! :)

Comment: you got it just in time... you're welcome...

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post the solution as an answer so this post is marked as Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace:

> Write #FileNum, DataLine

with:

> Print #FileNum, DataLine

because `Write #FileNum, DataLine` puts double quotes around the DataLine, so Excel treats entire line as one cell. **Print** does not include double quotes, so Excel can split the line into cells at each **TAB** character.